# Weyl Ordering of Fermions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, fermions

Consider Fermion operators $c^\alpha$ and their canonical conjugates $b_{\alpha}$ (satisfying $\{c^\alpha,b_{\beta}\}=\delta^\alpha_\beta$). Is there a prescription for Weyl ordering the following product:
$$
c^{\alpha_1}...c^{\alpha_n}b_{\beta_1}...b_{\beta_m}?
$$

Comment: [Gavazzi '89](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.528474).

Comment: @CosmasZachos, that article is behind a paywall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following excerpt from the paper suggested by Cosmas ([Gavazzi '89](https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jmp/article-abstract/30/12/2904/228678/Weyl-ordered-fermions-and-path-integrals?redirectedFrom=fulltext)):
[image]

So the answer is that it is the graded average of all permutations of the operators (where graded means we multiply by a minus (plus) sign for an odd (even) number of permutations). For example:
$$
\left(c^{\alpha_1}c^{\alpha_2}b_{\beta_1}\right)_W=\frac{1}{6}(c^{\alpha_1}c^{\alpha_2}b_{\beta_1}-c^{\alpha_1}b_{\beta_1}c^{\alpha_2}-b_{\beta_1}c^{\alpha_2}c^{\alpha_1}+b_{\beta_1}c^{\alpha_1}c^{\alpha_2}-c^{\alpha_2}c^{\alpha_1}b_{\beta_1}+c^{\alpha_2}b_{\beta_1}c^{\alpha_1})
$$
where $(\cdot )_W$ denotes Weyl ordering.